# using JPA ( hibernate) VS stored procedures

Tags: mysql, database, hibernate, stored-procedures

I am working on a project using ZK Framework, Hibernate, Spring and Mysql.

I need to generate some charts from Mysql database, but after I calculate the number of objects that I need to calculate the values of those charts I found it more than 1400 objects and same numbers of queries and transactions.

So i thought if using stored procedures in Mysql to calculate those values and save them in a separate tables (using an architecture close to Data Warehouse), and then use my web application to just read the values of those tables and display them as charts.

I want to know in terms of speed and performance, which of those methods is better?

And thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No way to tell, really, without many more details. However:

What you want to do is called Denormalisation. This is a recognised technique for speeding up reporting and making it easier. (If it doesn't, your denormalisation has failed!) When it works it has the following advantages:

- Reports run faster
- Report code is easier to write

On the other hand:

- Report Data is out of date, containing only data as at the time you
  last did the calculations

An extreme form of doing this is to take the OLTP database (a standard database) and export it into an Analysis database (aka a Cube or an OLAP database).

One of the problems of Denormalisation is that a) it is usually a significant effort, b) it adds extra code which adds complexity and thus increases support costs, and  c) it might not make enough (or any) difference. Because of this, it is usual not to do it until you **know** you have a problem. This will happen when you have done your reports on the basic database and have found that they either are too difficult to write and/or run too slowly. I would strongly suggest that only when you reach that point do you go for Denormalisation.

There can be times when you don't need to do that, but I've only seen 1 such example in over 25 years of development; and that decision was helped by a desire to use an OLAP database by Management for political purposes.